# How can I display +/- icons on my tree view?

Tags: c++, winapi, treeview

I want to make a tree view where items show a "+" icon when closed and a "-" icon when open. Just like the Windows XP explorer. However, I can't find out how to get the icons. Do I get them from the system or do I need to provide my own?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The tree-view control will display the icons if you set the `TVS_HASBUTTONS` [style](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb760013%28VS.85%29.aspx).

Comment: Thanks! Just found out myself actually :)